# Cannot Edit Imported Control in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have imported a control called ctrlTreeViewMutiCtrl into my vb.net project. So, in my toolbox, under test components, there is an option to add the ctrlTreeViewMutiCtrl object into Form1. However, when I try to edit the tree view control (the commands I used I was told to use from the website through which I downloaded the control) and then run the program, the tree view control I loaded into Form1 does not change at all. Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
    Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CtrlTreeViewMultiCtrl1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub CtrlTreeViewMultiCtrl1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CtrlTreeViewMultiCtrl1.Load
    Dim row1, row2 As ctrlTreeViewMultiCtrl.Row
    Dim tvmc As New ctrlTreeViewMultiCtrl

    tvmc.AddColumn("Column 1")
    tvmc.AddColumn("Column 2")
    tvmc.AddColumn("Column 3")
    tvmc.AddColumn("Column 4")

    tvmc.Head.SetControl(0, "Head Node")

    row1 = tvmc.Head.AddChild()
    row1.SetControl(0, "Sub Node 1")

    row2 = row1.AddChild()
    row2.SetControl(0, "Row 1")
    row2.SetControl(1, "Text 1")
    row2.SetControl(2, New DateTimePicker())
    row2.SetControl(3, "Sample 4")
    row2.Controls(3).ForeColor = Color.Red

    row2 = row1.AddChild()
    row2.SetControl(0, "Row 2")
    row2.SetControl(1, "Text 2")
    row2.SetControl(2, New DateTimePicker())
    row2.SetControl(3, "Sample 5")
    row2.Controls(3).ForeColor = Color.Green

    row1 = tvmc.Head.AddChild()
    row1.SetControl(0, "Sub Node 2")

    row2 = row1.AddChild()
    row2.SetControl(0, "Row 3")
    row2.SetControl(1, "Text 3")
    row2.SetControl(1, "Text 6")
    row2.SetControl(2, New DateTimePicker())
    row2.SetControl(3, "Sample 10")
    row2.Controls(3).ForeColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have created new instance of ctrlTreeViewMultiCtrl but seems never used. Where you want to show this control.?

Comment: @AnubrijChandra Thanks for responding! I would like to show the control in Form1.

Comment: Can you please better elaborate the question , is this asp.net page, then you need to inherit System.Web.UI.Page and add your control as  Me.Page.Controls.Add(ctrlTreeViewMultiCtrl)

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to VB.net. Are you saying that I should import System.Web.UI.Page and then add ctrlTreeViewMultiCtrl programmatically instead of right clicking on the project and "adding an existing item"?